# How to change the value of a key in a nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

```
{
 {'city':1 ,'person':{'name': 'John', 'age': '27'}},
 {'city':2 ,'person':{'name': 'Marie', 'age': '22'}},
 {'city':3 ,'person':{'name': 'Luna', 'age': '24'}},
 {'city':4 ,'person':{'name': 'Peter', 'age': '29'}}
}
```

How to change the age of the person in city 2 ?

And the second part of my question is that in Python which data structure is the most relevant in this case

Comment: This is not a dictionary.

Comment: That's better. But do you simply want to modify the age of the person at `data[1]`, or do you also need to find the dict with `'city':2`, in case you don't know its position in the list?

Comment: need to find the dict with 'city':2 first

Comment: You still haven't shown us your attempt at coding this. I didn't downvote, but that's probably the main reason your question got that many downvotes.

Comment: The solution is easy with some loops but the actual reason of asking the question is to find out a better way using where condition with lamda or pydash

Comment: You have a list, so you can't avoid some looping. If you need to do multiple searches it may be a good idea to create a new data structure so you can instantly find the dict of a person at a given city. But as Eugene asked, what do you want to do if there's a city with more than one person?

Comment: BTW `lambda` isn't magic, it's just a way to create simple anonymous functions, and often it's better to use a proper `def` to create the function.

Comment: @Barny Please do not fix your question's code with the provided answer, otherwise the question makes no sense for future users.

Answer (score 4):

You'd better use list of dicts, and make `age` integer:

```
data = [
 {'city':1, 'person': {'name': 'John', 'age': 27}},
 {'city':2, 'person': {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 22}},
 {'city':3, 'person': {'name': 'Luna', 'age': 24}},
 {'city':4, 'person': {'name': 'Peter', 'age': 29}}
]
person_by_city_id = {item['city_id']: item['person'] for item in data}
person_by_city_id[2]['age'] = 23
```

But data scheme is weird (what if we have 2 persons from one city - which of the ages we need to alter?)

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks, updated my code